# Why would SQL Server Adjust a DateTime for DST?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, vb.net

I have a stored procedure that takes a table-valued parameter.

One of the values in that table is a datetime. I've shown it sometimes adjusts the time back an hour for DST by running a query that counts when the time part of this date is not `00:00` (it should always be `00:00`) and it is or isn't DST.

This is causing problems. Basically this is how it's passed to the procedure:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("2015-05-15 00:00");
aDataTable.rows(0).("column") = dt;
someCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tvp", aDataTable);
```

And the procedure doesn't alter the time.

Debugging, I am reading the value of the datetime immediately before the procedure executes, and it is `2015-05-15 00:00`, but it gets stored to the database as `2015-05-14 23:00`.

Would SQL Server ever change the time for DST? How, when, why? What should I be looking for here?

Comment: Are your machine and your SQL server in the same time zone?  Do they have the same locale settings?

Comment: @DStanley, if this matters, I have a more fundamental question: how do I persist a time without needing to worry about that? The time should be independent of settings; it needs to be the explicit value provided to the procedure.

Comment: There's not one right answer - but if you need to support clients in multiple time zones than I would store dates in UTC on the server and let the client convert to their local time zone.  I'm not an expert in working with multiple time zones so there are definitely better opinions out there.

Comment: Why use a DateTime data type when Date is enough? are you working on a very old version of sql server?

Comment: What's the [`DataColumn.DateTimeMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datetimemode(v=vs.110).aspx) for that column in your `DataSet`?

Comment: @ZoharPeled bureaucracy...

Comment: AFAIK, SQL Server doesn't adjust datetime values for DST. Are you able to come up with a simple, complete example (including both C# and SQL code) that reproduces the issue?